# Python plotly choropleth does not work with GeoJSONs

Tags: python, geojson, choropleth, plotly

I am trying to use plotly choropleth to draw the map, lets say for a random variable of num for each of the feature regions of the map in Italy. However, it does not work. below is the code that I use:

I have downloaded the GeoJSON files for Italy from [here.](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/)

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import json
pio.renderers.default='browser'

with open('it-all.geo.json') as f:
     geojson = json.load(f)

n_provinces = len(geojson['features'])

province_names = [geojson['features'][k]['properties']['name'] for k in range(n_provinces)]

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,110):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)

datadata = pd.DataFrame({'province':province_names, 'num':randomlist}) 

fig = px.choropleth(datadata, geojson=geojson, color="num",
                    locations="province", featureidkey="properties.name",
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis")

fig.show()
```

What I am getting is a mixed shape map as below. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?
[image]